# What exactly does "apt purge ?config-files" do?

Tags: debian, apt

I read this command in a posting about Raspberry. With a web search, I found several Ask Ubuntu answers, but I don't know the details of this command.

```
apt purge ?config-files
```

What does this do, exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`apt purge '?config-files'`¹ (or `apt purge '~c'` for short) removes config files of the packages that have been removed.

When you do a `apt remove package`, the package is removed, but config files are preserved in case you install it again. With `apt remove --purge package` or `apt purge package` you will remove also config files.

The command, you are asking about, removes config files for all the packages you removed, but did not use `purge` or `remove` with `--purge` switch.

Those `?config-file`/`~c` patterns are documented in [the `apt-patterns` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/apt/apt-patterns.7.en.html).

> `?config-files,` ~c`
> Selects packages that are not fully installed, but have solely residual configuration files left.

Derived from [the ones in `aptitude`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html).

---

<sup>¹ `?` is a globbing character in all shells and must be quoted. If not, `?config-files` would be expanded to the list of filenames that start with a single character followed by `config-files` in the current working directory and in many shells (`csh`, `tcsh`, `fish`, `zsh`, `bash -O failglob`) would fail with an error if there are no such files (or expand to nothing if the `nullglob` option is enabled where available); `~` is also special in most shells.</sup>

Comment: can be safely tested as non-root with `apt --simulate purge '?config-files'`

Comment: "config files" is an over-simplification. `apt purge` removes **everything** that was not removed by `apt remove`, and this includes configuration files, right, but also the database associated with the package, the dedicated user and group that were created during installation, etc, etc

Comment: But *everything* can also be said to be wrong. The system (i.e. `dpkg`/`apt`)/package has no way of knowing e.g. which users has run the program so it can't remove config files etc. in the users' homedirs.